# Html non straight border liner for tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make a table via Html/Css (Javascript if needed) which basically looks like this:

[image: Sample Table]

As you can see there every row in this table has a bottom border, which starts above an image in the table, and then goes down to the other columns.
Is there any way to do this? (Maybe with a transparent image?)

Comment: how well do you know box model? It is in theory do-able without images.

Comment: The only way i could think of doing this is with images as aposed to border values.

Comment: not sure box model will do diagonal lines. I would create a .png image with the two arrows and the two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a psudo element with a rotation to solve this:

Check out this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zRMLr/

You will likely have to play with the numbers a lot to get it to work with whatever you want.

what I used in this demo (no images) BUT only works for IE9+

html:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><div></div></td><td></td><td>Some sort of text</td></tr>
    <tr><td><div></div></td><td></td><td>Some sort of text</td></tr>
    <tr><td><div></div></td><td></td><td>Some sort of text</td></tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table {
    width: 400px;
}

td:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    width: 20px;
}

td:first-child:after {
    content: '';
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    width: 28px;
    height: 1px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    top: -5px;
    left: 24px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
}

td:first-child div {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 14px;
}

td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but complicated. Is there also a way to trigger this only on mouseover?

Comment: For example that all rows are normal. But when you hover over one, than that row shows the border.

Comment: what do you mean "normal"?

Answer (score 0):

What you may do to achieve the desired effect is:

> 1. Create a div with a left/right border
> 2. Rotate using CSS3 rules the div to give this effect

Or

> 1. create a div with a left/right border
> 2. use border radius to have the desired effect

I hope this helps, if you would like I can bring some sample of code for you